# Create an image2D from a uint64_t image handle

Tags: opengl, glsl, nvidia

To use bindless images in OpenGL, you need to create a GLuint64 handle using *glGetImageHandleARB*. You can then set this handle to a uniform image2D variable and use the image as if you had bound it the old way. No problems with that. With textures/samplers, it is further possible to set the (texture) handle not to a sampler2D, but to a plain uniform uint64_t variable. This handle can then be used to "construct" a sampler object at runtime with the constructor *sampler2D(handle)*.

[The extension description says:](https://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/bindless_texture.txt)

> Samplers are represented using 64-bit integer handles, and may be
> converted to and from 64-bit integers using constructors.

and

> Images are represented using 64-bit integer handles, and may be
> converted to and from 64-bit integers using constructors.

So I would assume that the construction for images works the same way as it does for samplers, but this is not the case. Sample code:

```
#version 450
#extension GL_ARB_bindless_texture : enable
#extension GL_NV_gpu_shader5 : enable

layout(bindless_image, rgba8) uniform image2D myBindlessImage;

uniform uint64_t textureHandle;
uniform uint64_t imageHandle;

void main()
{
    sampler2D mySampler = sampler2D(textureHandle); // works like a charm
    ... = texture(mySampler, texCoord);

    ... = imageLoad(myBindlessImage, texCoordI); // works like a charm

    layout(rgba8) image2D myImage = image2D(imageHandle); // error C7011: implicit cast from "uint64_t" to "int"
    ... = imageLoad(myImage, texCoordI);
}
```

Apparently, neither the image2D(uint64_t) constructor nor the image2D(uvec2) constructor mentioned in the extension description are known to the compiler. Am I missing something here or is this simply not implemented right now, although it should be? The video driver I am using right now is Nvidia's 355.82. I would be glad if someone could shed some light on whether this works with any other driver/vendor's card.

By the way, why would I need that feature: In contrast to texture handles, image handles do not identify the whole underlying data, but only one texture level. If you want to do any mipmap or otherwise hierarchical work in shaders and need to bind several/all texture levels, you could provide the handles of all levels in a buffer and then construct them at shader runtime as needed. Right now, you have to define n different uniform image2Ds for your n texture levels, which is rather tedious, especially if the image size changes.

Addendum: The fastest way to reproduce the compile error is to just put *image2D(0lu);* somewhere in your shader code.

Comment: images can be written to by a compute shader, while textures are read only.

Comment: The extension spec does not mention any of the `samperType(uint64_t)` or `imageType(uint64_t)` constructors you are using.  The extension provides constructors as follows: `any image type(uvec2)       // Converts a pair of 32-bit unsigned integers to an image type`. It never mentions `uint64_t` at all, which is not a type of GLSL core, and neither one defined in this extension at all.

Comment: You are right, uint64_t is defined in the vendor-specific extension GL_NV_gpu_shader5. However, this does not change the problem. Even writing image2D(uvec2(0)); yields the exception "implicit cast from "uint64_t" to "int"".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax you're using is wrong. The correct syntax to cast a uint64_t to an image is:

```
layout(rgba8) image2D myImage = layout(rgba8) image2D(imageHandle);
```

It is required to specify the format multiple times. I have no idea why, nor why it's even required to specify the format at all. The spec is woefully vague on this.

Comment: This indeed solves the problem. Thank you very much! Too bad the compiler could not come up with a helpful error message.

Comment: I wish I could give you a hug. You just put an end to a several-hour-long struggle. Grace and peace to you, in the name of Jesus.